# How to integrate data from two datasets with different dates?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Imagine two datasets. Dataset df1 is the day of the year that a certain event occurred. Df1 has multiple other columns, but for the purpose of this question, only day matters. Df2 contains two columns, the day of the year a measurement was made, and the value of that measurement. Essentially, I want to create a new column ("AVG") in df1 that is the mean value of that day in df2 plus the value from the previous day. For example, the AVG for day 2 in df1 would be 12.5 ((10+15)/2).

Some example data below.

```
df1 <- structure(list(day = c(2, 5, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), value = c(10, 
15, 8, 13, 7, 20, 25, 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Example final product below.

```
df3 <- structure(list(day = c(2, 5, 7), AVG = c(12.5, 10, 22.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` from `dplyr` to get the previous value so that you can calculate the rolling means.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(AVG = (value + lag(value)) / 2, .keep = "unused") %>% 
  right_join(df1, by = "day")

#   day  AVG
# 1   2 12.5
# 2   5 10.0
# 3   7 22.5
```

Or by `zoo::rollmeanr()`:

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(AVG = zoo::rollmeanr(value, 2, fill = NA), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  right_join(df1, by = "day")

#   day  AVG
# 1   2 12.5
# 2   5 10.0
# 3   7 22.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with indexes around positions like this using `base R`. It is easy to compute the mean as you only want that measure for only two values. Finally, you can assign the result to your `df1`:

```
#Detect position
i1 <- which(df2$day %in% df1$day)
#Extract values
j1 <- df2$value[i1]
j2 <- df2$value[i1-1]
#Compute mean
j3 <- (j1+j2)/2
#Assign
df1$AVG <- j3
```

Output:

```
  day  AVG
1   2 12.5
2   5 10.0
3   7 22.5
```